# How to read image stored as byte in informix database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, handler, informix

I have images stored in the database in byte data type . And i get the byte array as the following :

```
Stream photo_stream = Photo_DAL.RetrievePhoto(int.Parse(reg);
byte[] photo_bytes = Photo_DAL.StreamToByteArray(photo_stream);
```

but I don't know how to make the imageurl ="some url"??

I search and find some articles about handler , but really i don't know how to use it.please How to read the image like this with some explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I search and find some articles about handler , but really i don't know how to use it

You could add a generic handler to your page (`MyImage.ashx`):

```
public class MyImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageId = context.Request["imageId"];
        // use the image id to fetch the photo bytes from the backend
        byte[] photoBytes = ...
        // ensure the content type matches the one of your image
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(photoBytes);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

and then in some web form you could point the `ImageUrl` property of an `Image` control to the generic handler and pass the id of the image as query string parameter:

```
<asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/myimage.ashx?imageid=123" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot .what if the user has no image, i have a static one in my folder ?and i want to put many content types `png`,`jpg`, ....

Comment: @just_name, if it's a static image you don't bother with generic handlers. In this case you directly reference it: `<asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/noimage.png" />`. And if yuo want to handle multiple image types you will have to store this information along with the image in your database. Then in addition to fetching the image bytes you will also fetch the corresponding content type from your db.

Comment: no i wanna to check if there 's no image in the database then put my static one ?

Comment: @just_name, in this case from your generic handler simply `byte[] photoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/images"), "noimage.png"));` and then write the `photoBytes` to the response the same way.